# Azure functionapp tutorial: Stopped at NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Stuck (during a deadline, of course) in the Azure Functionapp [Quickstart: Create a C# function in Azure from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=in-process%2Cazure-cli) by the error `NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`. A websearch for download `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages` led to me [Create an offline installation - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) which led me to [Create an offline installation of Visual Studio Step 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#step-1---download-the-visual-studio-bootstrapper) which told me to download the Visual Studio Professional "bootstrapper". That just seems to update Viusual Studio. And I still get the error.

Comment: Can you do a Prerequisite Check of your code and let me know the result follow the steps  from images to check https://i.imgur.com/x3KHSWm.png and https://i.imgur.com/f9ln00R.png

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 ways to resolve this

**WAY-1:**  Try reinstalling the latest .Net SDK again.

**WAY-2:**  Add nuget.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

**WAY-3:** Add Restore Packages step to the build pipeline

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(serviceLocation)/**/*.csproj'
    includeNuGetOrg: true
```

REFERENCES :

1. [Fix error NU1101: Unable to find package. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages · Hossam Barakat](https://www.hossambarakat.net/2020/06/24/fix-error-NU1101/).
2. [Can't compile: Seems to require Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions · Issue #80462 · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/80462)
3. [VS 2019 Manage Nuget Packages has only Offline packages (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86aad234-8c71-4f76-a751-2fd6b98d493b/vs-2019-manage-nuget-packages-has-only-offline-packages?forum=vssetup)